# Add column at Azure DevOps boards

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I use Azure DevOps boards for my projects, I am working on scrum methodology.

I want to add my customize columns at the sprints, I make a lot of research and I found it is possible at boards section not on the sprint.

my question here is it possible or not and if yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sprint task board you can't add new custom columns.

But, you can use [inherited process template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process), then add a new state to the Task work item and you will see it in the sprint board:

[image]

[image]